# ASUS P5B Plus motherboard - no any drives found - how to restore RAID array?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, raid, sata

We have a small server machine with an ASUS P5B Plus motherboard and 4 SATA HDDs. The HDDs were configured in a RAID10 array. Up until now, everything worked fine, but now the system doesn't recognize the drives. BIOS is set to RAID, jMicron controller is set to RAID, yet I can't see any of the drives in the BIOS setup, and jMicron BIOS tells me "no any drives found"

The HDDs all spin up, I hear no clicking sounds or anything that would suggest HDD error.

I did a search on this problem and replaced the SATA cables as suggested, but nothing's changed.

It is not a critical server and there's only one database running on it (which I have backup of), but I don't want to setup the server from scratch if not necessary.

What should I try to restore the RAID array and put the server back to working order?

I changed the CMOS battery, but it didn't solve the problem.

Looks like the culprit was the PSU. That's strange, because the voltages were good on the PSU, but after I installed a new PSU, everything went back to normal. I have my RAID array and the system is up and working.
What the hell could have happened to that PSU?

Comment: I cannot boot into the system. There are only those 4 drives and the system was on the RAID volume too.

Comment: It was set up with the ICH8 (fake RAID) via BIOS. The strange thing is, I cannot access the RAID console, CTRL+I does nothing...

Comment: The symptoms tell you that the RAID controller has likely failed. And the recourse you usually have in such a situation is to get a replacement mobo; you've probably spent more time fiddling with it than that would cost.  Yes, it happens. I love that board, but it's usually <$200 to replace & "stuff happens".  Or, get in touch with ASUS; their tech support is reliable as a rule, even out-of-warranty, and they can likely tell you if it's a hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Once more abusing the answer field for a large comment with images</sup>

*"I can't see any of the drives in the BIOS setup,"*

This is actually quite bad. This means that there is a problem even before you try to load from the array. We can ignore drivers and OS problems as well as my previous comments about the event log. The problem occurs before all that is relevant.

You should be able to connect the drives to four of the six SATA ports from the ICH8R chip. The BIOS should detect them.  If you see this then no drives are connected, no drives have power or something on-board broke.

[image: BIOS configuration screen from the Asus P5b plus manual, page 4.3]

With no disks detected there is nothing to configure as RAID, which is probably the reason you do not even get the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> option. You should be able to test with this going to the IDE configuration screen and changing the options between [RAID] and [AHCI]/[IDE]

[image: Asus P5b plus BIOS - SATA configuration screen]

Note that all these configurations are for the six ports supported by the ICH8R southbridge. That is the part which supports RAID-10. I assume the jmicron parts are not used at all, these only support RAID0/1 (but not 10) and eSATA.

(Image of a detected drive in your BIOS)

[image: Image of the Asus P5B plus BIOS with a detected drive]

If all of this fails then take a single drive to another computer and verify that it works. I assume that the drives are fine and will be detected when you try this (The alternative if four drives failing at the same time. Not all that likely).  And that means that you have a problem with the motherboard or its configuration.

If it is the configuration then download [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5B-PLUS/e3077_p5b-plus.pdf) and go to page 5.5.3 Intel RAID configurations. Sadly this only describes how to create a new RAID array and that seems to format it. So that means restoring from backup. Not fun.

[image]

(I hope that I am wrong here and that there is an option to re-add an array or that it auto detects the array. However I did not see that in the BIOS and I do not have any P5B plus boards to test with).

Anyway. Awaiting feedback. :-)

Comment: Ok, it clearly looks like a motherboard failure. If I switch back to IDE mode, no HDD is detected. Tried one HDD in another machine with the same SATA cable and it's OK, even the SMART is good. My suspicion is backed up by the fact that the mobo only switches on on the 2nd/3rd try.

Comment: OK, I found the cuplrit: it was the PSU. The motherboard is OK. It works fine with the new PSU. This was the second Chieftec unit that died in the last 2 months... strange.

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it. That way it can be found by future visitors . It will also prevent this post from being bumped up by 'community' until it gets an answer. -- And on a different note: Any other PSU's dying? Are the 'servers' on known bad power or on a UPS? Or it might just be bad luck, statistics on two units is less than optimal, but writing down what failed and when it did is a good idea for your IT staff cq. the people who maintain your servers.  (And yes, I realise that with DevOps servers this might not succeed).